# ORM library for automatically mapping foreign keys in Python or Ruby

Tags: python, ruby, database, orm

A frequent task I run into at work is writing scripts against pre-existing databases. Sometimes I'm connecting to Oracle, other times it might be MySql or even sql server.

What I would like is a tool which would reverse-engineer the database's tables and foreign keys and allow me to write OO-style scripts against the database. This could be in any language really, but python or ruby would be preferred.

For example - this is my ideal ruby script: (assuming the manager and employee tables already exist with foreign keys)

```
DB = Database.connect(connect_string)
DB.managers.each do |manager|
  puts manager.name
  manager.employees.each do |employee|
    puts employee.name
  end
end
```

Does this type of library exist? If so, it would save me so much time!

**Edit - the main feature I would like is for it to automatically discover foreign key associations from the database metadata without explicitly mapping them - I have tried ActiveRecord, SQLAlchemy, Sequel, and DataMapper, and from what I can tell, none of them can do this.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should take a look at the [SQLSoup extension](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/05/reference/ext/sqlsoup.html) in [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/). It claims to do all this for you (including foreign keys). I haven't tested it myself.

Comment: This is as close as I think I'm going to get - I still have to declare relations, but it's pretty easy: db.managers.relate('employees', db.employees)

Answer (score 3):

Serious Ruby ORMs don't do this for a reason: it's inflexible, not explicit enough and too much magic.

If you *really* want this in your project, try coding it yourself in Ruby. Here's what I've done in 5 minutes on top of ActiveRecord:

```
require 'active_record'

class ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.magic!
    connection.tables.map { |table|
      klass = Class.new(self)
      Object.send(:const_set, table.singularize.camelize, klass)
    }.each { |model|
      model.column_names.grep(/_id$/).each { |foreign_key|
        name = foreign_key.sub(/_id$/, '')
        model.belongs_to(name)
        name.camelize.constantize.has_many(model.name.tableize)
      }
    }
  end
end
```

Let's set up our database tables and have `magic!` analyze them:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:adapter => 'sqlite3', :database => ':memory:')

ActiveRecord::Schema.define do
  create_table "managers" do |t|
    t.string "name"
  end
  create_table "employees" do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.belongs_to "manager"
  end
end

# it happens!
ActiveRecord::Base.magic!
```

Create some test records and use it in the way you wanted:

```
mislav = Manager.create :name => "Mislav"
mislav.employees.create(:name => "Josh")
mislav.employees.create(:name => "Mike")

Manager.all.each do |manager|
  puts manager.name
  manager.employees.each do |employee|
    puts employee.name
  end
end
```

[Full code available on this Gist](http://gist.github.com/255584).

This only works with `belongs_to` and `has_many` associations. If you need a real library that does this and much more, check out [Dr Nic's Magic Models](http://magicmodels.rubyforge.org/dr_nic_magic_models/).

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for your well thought out response.

 I agree that basing the names on column naming conventions would be a bad idea, but really I'm looking for a library which would analyze the foreign keys in the database metadata to find the associations.

Looking at the ruby database drivers, it seems that most of them don't keep any info about foreign keys, which would make this very difficult. I know that most JDBC drivers store this info, so maybe I could use JRuby to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [sqlautocode](http://code.google.com/p/sqlautocode/) module for SQLAlchemy. It will generate the ORM classes by reflecting the database.

Answer (score -2):

In Ruby there are several ORMs like [ActiveRecord](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html), [DataMapper](http://datamapper.org/) or even [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/).

For example using ActiveRecord you would do:

```
##################################
#mysql conection
##################################
begin
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
    :adapter  => DBAdapter,
    :host     => DBHost,
    :username => DBUserName,
    :password => DBPass,
    :database => DBDatabase,
    :encoding=> DBEncoding,
    :socket=> DBSocket #drop this option for windows machines 
  )
rescue Exception => ex
  fout.puts "Error connecting to mysql : #{ex}"
  puts "Migration was terminated due to connection error , check out the log file"
  break
end

######################
# Define models
######################

class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :manager
end 

class Manager < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :employees
end
```

Comment: These libraries all require you to set up the associations manually.